# Javascript set checkbox checked between selected values

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked

Following the code

```
<select id="choice_option">
    <option value="00">Hourly</option>
    <option value="15">15 minutes</option>
    <option value="30">30 minutes</option>
    <option value="45">45 minutes</option>
</select>

<select id="from_time">
    <option value="6:00">6:00</option>
    <option value="7:00">7:00</option>
    <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
    ...
</select>

<select id="to_time">
    <option value="6:00">6:00</option>
    <option value="7:00">7:00</option>
    <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
    ...
</select>

<input type="checkbox" value="6:00" class="times" />6:00
<input type="checkbox" value="6:00" class="times" />6:15
<input type="checkbox" value="6:00" class="times" />6:30
<input type="checkbox" value="6:00" class="times" />6:45
<input type="checkbox" value="6:00" class="times" />7:00
<input type="checkbox" value="6:00" class="times" />7:15
<input type="checkbox" value="6:00" class="times" />7:30
<input type="checkbox" value="6:00" class="times" />7:45
...
var choice = document.getElementById('choice_option');

Event.add('choice_option', 'change', function() {
    checkTimes(choice);
});

var checkTimes = function(elem) {
    var from = document.getElementById('from_time'),
        to = document.getElementById('to_time'),
        times = document.querySelectorAll('.times'),
        len = times.length,
        i, t, startTime, stopTime;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        t = times[i].value.slice(-2);
        startTime = from.options[from.selectedIndex].value;
        stopTime = to.options[to.selectedIndex].value;

        if(times[i].checked) {
            times[i].checked = false;
        }

        if(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value == t) {
            times[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is set the `check boxes` as checked between users's selected hours "`from_time`" and "`to_time`".

I made it till the point where check boxes get checked based on :`00, :15, :30` or 45 minutes. But I'm stuck when the checked boxes should be between selected times.

So if user chooses 15 minutes and from 06:00 to 14:00 I want every `checkbox` which has the value `6:15, 7:15`, `8:15` ... `14:15` to be checked.

I tried to compare the "`from_time`" and "`to_time`" but no luck so far.

Thank you

Comment: can you use jquery in your project?

Comment: I can, but I don't want to since the app it doesn't require much javascript, so I don't need the overload of jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. What I should've done was this

instead of

```
if(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value == t) {
   times[i].checked = true;
}
```

i changed to

```
if(startTime <= times[i].value && stopTime >= times[i].value 
&& elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value == t) {
    times[i].checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a simpler approach...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEBQre

```
<select id="fromHour">
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

<select id="fromMinutes">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
</select>

<span>to</span>

<select id="toHour">
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

<select id="toMinutes">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
</select>
```

Comment: alright, good tip, but how do I select the checkboxes between lets say 6:15 and 15:15, and take out 12:15 since the user it's not available at that time? the problem is that I can't see the logic on how to select the checkboxes withing the time frame

Comment: you would use if else statements to to determine what props are disabled based on user selection.